# Hosting a WF TextBox in a WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, xaml

I am making a WPF application in vb.net

I currently have a DataGrid that has a DataTable source attached to it to retrieve values from.

The DataGrid has its columns defined in my vb code. The DataTable itself is updated in the vb code as well.

I was able to figure out how to define DataGridTextColumns/DataGridTemplateColumns to bind a DatePicker and Image to my Datagrid.

However, now I would like to bind a Windows Form Textbox as well.

I am able to use WindowsFormHost inside the XAML to create a WF TextBox, but I can't figure out how to bind this TextBox to my DataGrid. The TextBox has no Binding option, and I can't set the text={Binding name} either.

I noticed there is a BindingContext for the WF TextBox. Should I use this? If so, how do I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What's the problem with a wpf textbox?

Comment: the WF textbox has an auto-complete feature that I wanted to utilize